# For what $x\in{\bf R}$ does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln (n+x^2)}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For what values of $x\in{\bf R}$ does the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln (n+x^2)}}$$ converge?

---

For $x=0$, the series diverges by the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). For $|x|>0$, one might want to look at the integral
$$
\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{y\sqrt{\ln(y+x^2)}}\,dy,
$$
which I don't see how to give an estimate.

Comment: The general term is equivalent to $\frac1{n\sqrt{\ln n}}$ so the series diverges for every $x$.

Comment: @AmrAhmad: how would you show the "equivalency"?

Comment: @Jack If you check the solutions below, you have $$\frac{2}{x^2+2}\cdot \frac{1}{n \sqrt{\log n}} \le \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\log (n+x^2)}} \le \frac{1}{n \sqrt{\log n}}$$ for all $n\ge 2$ and all reals $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in{\bf R}$,
$$
1\le \frac{ \ln(n+x^2)}{\ln n}= \frac{\ln n + \ln(1+x^2/n)}{\ln n}\le \frac{\ln n + \ln(1+x^2)}{\ln n} \to 1.
$$

Use this and the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to see $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/[n(\ln^{1/2} n)]$ diverges iff $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/[n\ln^{1/2} (n+x^2)]$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in \mathbb R$ and $k\ge 2$ a positive integer, such that 
$\log k\ge x^2$. Then $kn\ge k+n$, and thus 
$\log(n+x^2)\le \log(n+k)$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\log (n+x^2)}}\ge \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\log n+\log k}}\ge \sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt{2\log n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\log n}}=\infty,
$$
since
$$
\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\log n}}\ge \int_{k}^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\log x}}=\int_{\log k}^\infty\frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}=\infty.
$$

Comment: Not entirely sure on your logarithms.  Is the first one $\log(n)+x^2$ or $\log(n+x^2)$?  :-/ And isn't this... basically my answer?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^k\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\log (n+x^2)}}&\asymp
\sum_{n=2}^k\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\log (n)}}
\ge\sum_{n=2}^k\frac{1}{n \log (n)}\\
&\asymp \int_2^k\frac{1/y}{\log y}\,\mathrm{d}y \asymp \log \log k
\end{align}
as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: The first inequality is not correct I think.

Comment: Yes, the first inequality is backwards.

Comment: $n+x^2 \le \left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)n$ for each $x$ and $n\ge 2$, where is the mistake?

Comment: ($f(k) \gg g(k)$ means that $f(k) \ge C g(k)$ for some positive constant $C=C(x)$.)

Comment: $\log(n+x^2) \leq \log\left(\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)n\right) = \log(n) + \log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$. How did you derive the first inequality is not clear.

Comment: And then $\log(n+x^2)<(1+\varepsilon)\log n$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ and $n$ sufficiently large. The constants are included in the symbol $\gg$.

Comment: Note that:
$$\ln(n+x^2)>\ln(n)\iff\frac1{\ln(n+x^2)}\boxed<\frac1{\ln(n)}$$

Comment: Oh, I see, though its a bit misleading as the $\gg$ points in the direction opposite of the $>/<$.

Comment: You are right, maybe $\asymp$ is better. I didn't use it just because it's a bit less used than $\gg$ (however, now I deleted all the $\gg$ to avoid confusion)

Comment: :P Well, I prefer direct inequalities for clarity.  By this point I think you are more or less following the route of limit comparisons.  Direct comparisons are more classy for my taste :P

Comment: I agree, your answer looks better for sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in{\bf R}$ and $k$ be some positive integer such that $k>x^2$. Then for *any* $n\geq k$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln(n+x^2)}}\geq
\frac1{n\sqrt{\ln(n+k)}}&>\frac1{n\sqrt{\ln(n+n)}}\\&>\frac1{n\sqrt{\ln(n\times n)}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac1{n\sqrt{\ln(n)}}\\&
\end{align}$$

Since you know that $\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\ln (n)}}$ diverges (the case when $x=0$), by the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test), $\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\ln (n+x^2)}}$ diverges as well.

Comment: Your proof shows that when $x \leq \sqrt{n}$, the series diverges. But what about larger values of $x$.

Comment: Note that nothing can be $>\infty.$

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 From a certain point, $x\le\sqrt{n}$ holds true ($x$ is fixed, and $n$ goes to $\infty$.)

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 Just take $k>x^2$, as my proof works for arbitrarily large $k$.

Comment: @zhw. :P Oh hush, you know what I mean.  Just a quick touch on what the direct comparison test is.

Comment: Oh yes. $x$ is fixed. My bad.

Comment: Sure I know what you mean. It would be better for MSE readers if your answer did not include nonsense however

Comment: @zhw. That better for you?

Comment: @Jack No problem :-)